# How to stop Angular App on 401 response

Tags: angularjs, ajax, authentication

Hey im building login system using angularjs. I have one thing which annoys me. For example i have page A with 2 rest request. The first request send some public data - you dont need auth for this, and some private - for current user.

My api check the token - for public data, becouse user always can delete cookies - error response send 401 and angular catch it, and check authience for api/me- similarly send 401. What's the problem? Or what annoying me?

In one page we have two request for api/me to see some private data (private buttons for example) and public data in one page, but when we have got unauth user (probably deleted a cookies) http interceptor catch 2x 401 response error, from api/me and api/public data. How can I solve this problem? Becouse it's doesn't matter how much 401 response we've got. The one 401 response is enough to state that we should logout user.

By the way I was interesting how fb check cookies, they doing it asynchronous becouse when we remove cookie names 'xs' server send request to ajax api then our fb is totally blocked. Where I can learn more about this technique ?

Comment: why can't you add error handler on /api/me error response and redirect to home page?

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of this question. Not clear at all what specific problem is

Comment: I want to block next 401 response error's becouse I need the only one to identify error unauth. @alexey use backend for redirect, yes?

Comment: not necessary, you can use angular for this

Answer (score 0):

basically the states within ui.router (which is used by professional developers instead of angulars default routing) , can be given a property to determine whether auth is required ...

```
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'routes/login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
    authenticate: false
  })
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'routes/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'homeCtrl',
    authenticate: true
  })
```

then you can use the authenticate property to determine if the state requires auth. on every state change you can make an http call to your isauthenticated api if the state requires auth. if that call returns 401 then call your logout function.

your logout function might clear auth cookies and send the user to the login state.

you can also watch for 401s in your http interceptor and deal with them how you think best.

Comment: Thanks for meaningful answers. @danday74 i can't clear auth cookies becouse i use httponly cookie so i have to do this in backend. is it ok to tell  interceptor when i've got 404 to bring to service? The service will logout with $http to our api for example to  api/logout ?

Comment: yes sorry thats also an important part of the logout procedure to call api/logout which will delete the cookie (forgot cookie would be httponly sorry). so yes tell the interceptor to call yoursevice.logout and inject your yourservice into the interceptor using the $injector service ... var loginService = $injector.get('LoginService'); loginService.logout();